# RestSharp on Response dont know how to call callback

Tags: c#, xamarin, restsharp

I´m using restsharp for getting data from a API that I´m doing, I would like to make a class called "ApiInterface" that will be used in Xamarin (Android, iOS, Windows...) to call to the API.

This class has its RestClient and funcions that will be called from any part of the code as it´s a singleton.

So for example I will have a MainActivity.cs something like this. (Calling to my getData function and doing stuff with the data that I received).

```
Button buttonListaIntereses = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);

buttonListaIntereses.Click += delegate {
    ApiInterface.Instance.getData(response2=>
    {
        Intent displayMessage = new Intent(this, typeof(DisplayMessage));
        //Put info in Extra for the new screen.
        displayMessage.PutExtra("content", response2.Content);
        StartActivity(displayMessage);
    });
};
```

But in the APIInterface I would like to get common data like cookies.

```
public async void getData(Action <IRestResponse> onDone)
{           
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest("getData", Method.GET);

   //Execute ASYNC the rest request
    m_Client.ExecuteAsync (request, response =>
    {
        //Do my stuff with headers.
        string lCookie = response.Headers.ToList().Find(x => x.Name == "Cookie").Value.ToString();
       //Execute the OnDone
       onDone();
    });
}
```

My problem is that I´m not sure how to execute my OnDone in the getData and/or how to call the getData function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would move away from using callbacks and take advantage of the Async / Await features of C#

```
buttonListaIntereses.Click += async delegate {
    var response = await ApiInterface.Instance.getData();
    LaunchResponseActivity(response);
};

public void LaunchResponseActivity(IRestResponse response)
{
    Intent displayMessage = new Intent(this, typeof(DisplayMessage));
    //Put info in Extra for the new screen.
    displayMessage.PutExtra("content", response.Content);
    StartActivity(displayMessage);
}

public async Task<IRestResponse> getData()
{           
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest("getData", Method.GET);

    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    var restResponse = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

    //Do my stuff with headers.
    string lCookie = restResponse.Headers.ToList().Find(x => x.Name == "Cookie").Value.ToString();

    return restResponse;
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrés, I haven´t tried you code, I´m new using the async/await c# features what are their advantages?

Comment: You were it was better changing all the interface for xamarin and its navigation flow.

Answer (score 1):

The Action parameter *onDone* takes a parameter of type *IRestReponse*:

```
public async void getData(Action<IRestResponse> onDone)
{           
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest("getData", Method.GET);

    //Execute ASYNC the rest request
    m_Client.ExecuteAsync (request, response =>
    {
        //Do my stuff with headers.
        string lCookie = response.Headers.ToList().Find(x => x.Name == "Cookie").Value.ToString();

        // Execute the onDone action with the received response
        onDone(response);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks lenkan!
I was stuck with that! :)